# php ffmpeg exec & shell_exec process stops after few seconds

Tags: php, shell, ffmpeg, exec

I'm using PHP script file with simple html interface to control FFMPEG process start and stop from the browser , the script goal is start live streaming on my server that usually runs for hours without stop (using ffmpeg and nginx-rtmp )
 my script were working perfectly until I notice recently This is strange behaviors 
here is my php script variables

```
$cast =" /usr/sbin/ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -thread_queue_size 32768 -re -i '".$src."' -i /var/www/example/logo.png -r 23.976 -strict -2 480x360 -aspect 16:9 -filter_complex 'overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)-23' -vcodec libx264 -x264opts colormatrix=bt709 -profile:v high444 4 -b:v 290k -maxrate 290k -bufsize 250k  -af "aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0" -acodec libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 16k -map_metadata -1 -f flv  rtmp://localhost/hls/live 2>/dev/null >/dev/null  & " ; 
$output =  shell_exec( $cast   )    ;
```

It's like FFMPEG process continue until original php process ( that call it ) die , at first I thought this issue with the sorce or ffmpeg command but I test the same command on the sell and it works perfectly .
My suspicion are with on STDIO etc were not  redirected right . even when I excute the same php script from the shell it's do the same stops after few seconds .

=Edit=

Even when I tried to run `ffmpeg` from the command line and make it run  on the background , I got same behavior the process stop after few seconds , ffmpeg continue running only if I wait for it output .

Here my OS details :-

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
```

Comment: You are sending the command to background, so it will return immediately. You will not get output from it. Also you should be using `escapeshellarg()` https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg

Comment: That page are locked with my IP address only , anyway the command does go to the background , but it's stops after short time , while I was able to running it from the shell for hours .

Comment: Try to add "nohup": "nohup /usr/sbin/ffmpeg ....".

Comment: Same thing `ffmpeg`  lives for short time , I think the issue are with `ffmpeg` program not PHP .

Comment: I can't find a reference but I seem to remember that any spawned background process will die when the apache request that triggered it ends. You can prevent that using `NOHUP` prefix for that shell_exec command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright alright after days of trying and invetstigation the issue looks like the main issue were with `ffpmeg` for unowen reason for me refuse to run without defining any output pipe , my guessing is the input stram had some frames dropped from time to time . anyway this is what I add to end of ffmpeg command

```
$cast ="< /dev/null /usr/sbin/ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -thread_queue_size 12768 -re -i \"$link/$chnl\" -r 23.976 -s 480x360  -vcodec libx264 -b:v $bitrate -minrate $bitrate -maxrate $bitrate -bufsize $bitrate -acodec aac -b:a 29k -map_metadata -1 -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/live  </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/www/vlc10/ffmpeg.log & " ;
exec(   $cast   ) ;
```

I was have to redirect `ffmpeg` to log file like this `</dev/null >/dev/null 2>/var/www/vlc10/ffmpeg.log &` eve `ffmpeg` had silent mode but it wont work "or at least crashed after few seconds ".

Comment: have you tried something like this without sending the process to background at the system level? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php#92413

Comment: -my code  "redirect command output to a file"- both `exec` `shell_exec` works perfectly . I didn't try `popen`/`pclose` yet

Answer (score 0):

PHP on CLI and PHP as FPM or Apache Module have different configs (php.ini)

So in your case you need to modify the [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) for the right environment.
You can set it in the corresponding php.ini or with ini_set() or with set_time_limit()

EDIT:
Maybe you want to switch to [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
But please keep in mind:

> If a program is started with this function,
>   in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of
>   the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream.
>   Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the
>   program ends.

And please use [escapeshellarg()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Comment: in fact the exec should not relay on `max_excution_time` setting , since it Supposed to be running on the background , and you forgot if set excution time to max , the browser will hang-on waiting for `ffmpeg` process to stop running .

Comment: I think it does relay on it, if you read the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php "Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string"
So it runs until process gives you a result which is the return value.

Comment: Please re-read the docs you're linking to and the question - specifically this bit: `2>/dev/null >/dev/null  &`. This is trivial to verify with a script like this `<?php shell_exec("sleep 30 2>/dev/null >/dev/null  &");`